# readLine() retornando null

Tags: java

Estou com um problema com meu código. Eu preciso acessar meu site e verificar a resposta que ele me dá. Porém o readLine retorna null (Fim da transmissão) logo na primeira e unica linha. Não apresenta nenhum erro, só retorna null (Ví por meio de debug).

```
    try {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://brunnw.cf/plugins.php?licenca=" + license);
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        yc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        yc.setReadTimeout(5000);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

        /*

        O site esta programado para responder apenas true ou false, 
        então eu não me preocupo com outras linhas, só a primeira.
        Por isso está assim, é de proposito

        */
        if(in.readLine() == "true") {

            ccs.sendMessage("§b[uRanking]§f Sua licença é válida! Plugin ativado com sucesso!");
            ccs.sendMessage("§b[uRanking]§f Obrigado por comprar meus plugins e por ser honesto :-)");

        } else {

            ccs.sendMessage("§4[uRanking]§f Sua licença não é válida!");
            ccs.sendMessage("§4[uRanking]§f Verifique o número de licenciamento e tente novamente.");
            ccs.sendMessage("§4[uRanking]§f O plugin será desabilitado por questões de segurança.");
            Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(plugin);

        }

    } catch(Exception e) {

             ccs.sendMessage("§4[uRanking]§f Não foi possível verificar sua licença. O plugin foi desativado por medidas preventivas.");
             Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(plugin);

    }
```

Comment: Por favor, poste a mensagem de erro completa

Comment: Como @AlexandreGuerreiro mencionou poste o erro todo, mas uma dúvida já experimentou ver mesmo que dados o   `in.readLine() ` está a retornar ( através de um variavel ou do debug), para ter a certeza que é null?

Comment: Considere usar `"true".equals(in.readLine())` ao invés de `in.readLine() == "true"`

Comment: Sim, eu fiz um debug e retorna exatamente null

Comment: @Brunno Só pra ter certeza, vc ta fazendo um plugin para servidor de Minecraft? kkk

Comment: @Francisco Sim :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca externa, [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), para transformar seu inputStream diretamente em uma string, já que você precisa somente da primeira linha.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://brunnw.cf/plugins.php?licenca=" + license);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();

    String body = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");    

    if(body.contains("true")) {
        //...
    }else {
        //...
    }
```